# jquery - function restart

Tags: jquery

I have never programmed in jquery. I'm using JQuery Countdown plugin for
to have a countdown when i call a php page but the timer doesn't restart.
I need to write a restart function to call by the 'onExpiry' event of the JQuery Countdown plugin. This is the script that i have on a html page.
I'm following this post :
[Auto Restart/Reset countdown timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932540/auto-restart-reset-countdown-timer)
but i think that the solution in that post doesn't work because is about dates.
I need to restart for a random period of maximum 2 hours.
Thanks.....

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function randRange() {
        var newTime = Math.floor(Math.random() * 30001) + 10000;
        return newTime;
    }

    function toggleSomething() {
        $('#timeval').load('ajaxTime.php?randval=' + Math.random());
        clearInterval(timer);
        lollo = parseInt(randRange());
        timer = setInterval(toggleSomething, lollo);
        $('#msg').fadeOut("slow").countdown({ *onExpiry:?????* until : +(lollo / 1000),
            format : 'HMS',
            layout : '<div id="timer">' + '<div class="timer_numbers">{hnn}:{mnn}:{snn}</div>' + '</div>'
        }).fadeIn("slow");
    }
    var timer = setInterval(toggleSomething, 1000);
});
```

EDIT:

I solved :

```
$('#msg').countdown({until: +(lollo/1000), onExpiry: function() { setTimeout(function() { $('#msg').countdown('change', {until: +((lollo/1000) - 1)}); }, 1000); }, format: 'HMS', layout:
    '<div id="timer">'+
        '<div class="timer_numbers">{hnn}:{mnn}:{snn}</div>'+
    '</div>'
    });
```

If anyone has a better solution please contact me    pro-zac31[at]libero.it .... !!! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
$(function() {
    function randRange() {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * 30001) + 10000;
    }

    (function resetTimer() {
        $('#msg').fadeOut("slow", function() {
            $(this).countdown('destroy').countdown({
                until: randRange() / 1000,
                format: 'HMS',
                layout: '<div id="timer">' + '<div class="timer_numbers">{hnn}:{mnn}:{snn}</div>' + '</div>',
                onExpiry: resetTimer
            }).fadeIn("slow");
        });
    })(); //self-execute
});
```